# WPF TextBox wrap a long line after a number of characters

Tags: wpf, textbox

I'm looking for a way to solve the particular task: have a resizable window with textbox which has minimum width. Here is a little concept:

```
<Window ...
        SizeToContent="Width"
        ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"><...></Menu>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"><...></StatusBar>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <RadioButton .../>
            <...>
        </RadioButton>
        <TextBox MinWidth="{Binding MinWidth}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"
                 FontFamily="Consolas"
                 FontSize="{Binding FontSize}"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 .../>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a two-column dialog with a stack of radiobuttons on the right side and textbox that takes all available space. I want to show at least N characters per line, so I'm using `FormattedText` to calculate the minimum width for text box to show these numbers of characters and setting the minimum width via binding. So when initialized, text box resized automatically depending on font size. So far so good.

The problem I face is that textbox is automatically resized upon typing and when string exceeds the initial width of textbox. Input line can be hundreds or thousands characters long and doesn't contain spaces or other charactes the wrap opportunity algorithm can use to wrap the line.

What I want is to mimic the behavior of Windows Notepad when WordWrap option is enabled. Notepad has some width and if I type a very long line, it automatically wraps the line without resizing the window. Wpf does resize textbox and window as well -- this is what I don't want. Also, I can't manipulate input string by inserting hidden characters so WPF can break on them as suggested in other similar questions.

Comment: How about setting MaxWidth?

Comment: Why do you have sizetocontent set on the window? This is a bit of an odd setting given your requirement.  Consider notepad or word. Nether would grow your window width as you type.  Partly because the window might not fit. Your user could be typing and the cursor is off screen.

Comment: Since I don't know the whole window size in advance, I set explicit minimum width (window is resizable and textbox width can be expanded) and let WPF to calculate the minimum width for window. Otherwise, WPF will set arbitrary width for window. Does it make sense for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could handle the `Loaded` and `SizeChanged` events for the window and set the `Width` property of the `TextBox` accordingly:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Width = double.NaN;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Width = tb.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```